# C++ file IO getline not pulling a string

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a file that is opened filled like this:

> STRING
>
> INT
>
> INT
>
> INT
>
> filename.txt
>
> STRING
>
> INT
>
> INT
>
> INT
>
> filename1.txt

etcetera

I have code that is supposed to read from the file, pull the string, the integers, and the file names. It is able to pull the string and the integers, but it won't pull the file name.

Here is the code:

```
while( !input.eof() )
{
   string name;
   int type = UNKNOWN;
   int pages;
   float ounces;
   getline( input, name );
   input >> type >> pages >> ounces;
   getline(input, reviewFile); //reviewFile is a static string called in the header file
   input.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
}
```

Comment: Try an extra getline.  You probably have the newline after the ounces still in the input buffer.

Comment: Or just `input >> type >> pages >> ounces >> ws` ...

Answer (score 0):

The operator>> will read words, not taking end of line into account that much.

Therefore, I would write something like this (As Massa wrote in a comment):

```
input >> type >> pages >> ounces >> ws;
```

Also, please note that "eof" checks are suboptimal. Try to avoid them. Moreover, you do not check after the reads within the loop if there is anything more to read.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you put the `ignore` before the getline, to eat the newline after the ounces:

```
while( !input.eof() )
{
   string name;
   int type = UNKNOWN;
   int pages;
   float ounces;
   getline( input, name );
   input >> type >> pages >> ounces;
   input.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
   getline(input, reviewFile); //reviewFile is a static string called in the header file
}
```